# execlp fails if I don't flush the buffer

Tags: c, exec

I'm trying to run a command in a child process in C:

```c
int main()
{
    if (fork()) {
        wait(0);
    } else {
        fflush(stdout);
        execlp("ls", "ls");
        printf("Command not found: \"%s\"\n", "ls");
    }   
}
```

My understanding is that the call to `fork()` will create a clone of the process (the child). The parent here will `wait(0)`, because `fork()` doesn't return null, and wait for the child process to be done.

I understand the child process' image essentially "becomes" `ls` after the call to `execlp("ls", "ls");`.

At this point, if `ls` exists in the path, the `ls` program takes over and the `printf()` on line 8 should never be called.

This works as expected with the snippet I posted above, and I get the output of `ls` in the current directory.

However if I **comment out** `fflush(stdout)`, the `printf()` gets called!

```
Command not found: "ls"
```

Why does the `printf()` get called if I comment out `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: Strange, I cant reproduce it. Did you try `bin/ls`?

Comment: `execlp()` wants `NULL` as last argument. You *always* need to specify it: `execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);`. Apart from that, your program is fine. If you're seeing that problem with some different code post *the actual code* that produced it. Also, use `perror("execlp failed")` after `execlp()` so that the correct error message is printed and you can understand what is going on.

Comment: regarding: `if (fork()) {
        wait(0);`  This will 'hang' forever, if the call to `fork()` fails.  The code needs to check for all three conditions returned from `fork()`

Comment: @user3629249 No it won't. The `wait(0)` will fail with `ECHILD` if the `fork()` failed. It will not hang.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `NULL` is not always safe as the last argument of `execl*` or other variadic functions. `NULL` can be defined to just `0`, instead of `((void*)0)` in which case an integer will be passed instead of a pointer, which may cause a crash on any platform where they're not the same size (ie any 64 bit machine like x86-64). `(void*)0` or `(char*)0` is better.

Comment: @mosvy If, as you say, `NULL` was defined to have some random wrong type, you would at least get a warning from the compiler. `some_ptr = 0;` *is* a perfectly valid assignment, even in the case of argument passing. It gives no error or warning whatsoever even if compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`. Integer constants also definitely *don't* have a predefined size, the compiler decides what size to use based on the expression. It's 2020, being scared of something that may break a badly designed 1989 compiler is just nonsense.

Comment: Defining `NULL` to `0` is not defining to "some random wrong type". It's perfectly OK according to the standard. `0` is the "null pointer constant" EVEN if the null pointer is `0xffffffff` or `0xdeadbeef`. What you apparently fail to see is that `execlp` is a __variadic__ function, there's no way for the compiler to know if the arguments passed are pointers or integers. gcc will actually warn you about it (something about sentinel iirc), but that's only because the headers use gcc extensions when defining the `execlp` function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "if __`0`__ arguments are pointers or integers" above. And it seems that it's even worse -- gcc makes a special case for `execlp` and `execle` by treating them as built-in functions, and assuming that they're always defined with `__attribute__((sentinel))`. Other compilers like clang don't seem to do that.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. for any error, properly passes 'your' error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`
5. passes a valid parameter list to `execlp()`
6. documents why each header file is included
7. uses a valid signature, as defined in the C programming language standard, for the `main()` function
8. does not make assumptions about the value returned from `fork()`
9. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // perror(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <unistd.h>   // execlp(), fork(), pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h> // wait()


int main( void )
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if ( pid < 0 ) 
    {   // then error
        perror( "fork failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( pid == 0 )
    {   // then child
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL );
        perror( "execlp failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    else
    {   // then parent
        wait(0);
    } 
}
```

Comment: [ditto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959730/execlp-fails-if-i-dont-flush-the-buffer#comment107853741_60959730)

Comment: my posted answer works perfectly, as written, using `gcc` for the compiler on ubuntu 18.04 linux.   If your having difficulties running the posted code, Then it has to be something in your environment

Comment: your code is UB, as already explained. there's nothing wrong with my environment

Comment: here is the syntax, per the MAN page, for execlp():  `int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);`  So where are you getting a UB problem?

Comment: I guess the people who wrote that manpage put the __`(char *) NULL`__ (just as I was suggesting) instead of just `NULL` (as in your code) because they were stupid and pedantical?

Comment: in C, parameters get promoted to the necessary type.  So no need to include the `(char *)`

Comment: No, integer arguments to a variadic function don't get "promoted" to pointers. That's an absurd notion. It would be trivially easy for you to dispel your misconceptions with some testing, but apparently you don't care a bit about the facts.

Comment: there are NO integer parameters in the posted answer.  Rather, each parameter becomes a pointer to a char string